# Can I partially derive Show?

Tags: haskell

I have written this code to pretty-print a tree:

```
data Node = A | B | C | Tree Node [Node]
    deriving (Show, Eq)

printTree' :: Int -> Node -> [String]
printTree' spaceCount (Tree node children) = (printTree' spaceCount node)
    ++ concat (map (\child -> printTree' (spaceCount+2) child) children)
printTree' spaceCount leaf = [(replicate spaceCount ' ') ++ (show leaf)]

printTree :: Node -> String
printTree node = unlines (printTree' 0 node)
```

Example output:

```
*Main> putStr $ printTree $ Tree A [Tree A [A,B,C], C]
A
  A
    A
    B
    C
  C
```

Now I would like to make this the implementation for `show`. This approach is close but I can't find a way to call the built-in `show`:

```
instance Show Node where
    show (Tree node children) = printTree (Tree node children)
    show _ = "node... can I call the built-in show here?"
```

(In this example, I could just deal with A, B, and C. But in the real code, there are many node types.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I can see to do this is to separate into two types.

```
data Tree node = Tree node [Tree node]
data Node = A | B | C deriving Show

instance Show node => Show (Tree node) where ....
```

Comment: Your definition of `Tree` gives a distinctly different datatype than the original definition of `Tree`. Something like `data Tree a = Tree a [Tree a] | Leaf a` would more closely match the original.

Answer (score 1):

Following MathematicalOrchid's reponse, the best way to do this is with a new type, but here's a better way to organize the types:

```
data Node = Leaf Leaf | Tree Node [Node] deriving Eq
data Leaf = A | B | C deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Show Node where
  show (Tree node children) = printTree (Tree node children)
  show (Leaf l) = show l
```